# What is the use of (int) inside the value of int variable?

Tags: java

What is the use of (int) in this line of code?

```
int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);
```

I do not know the use/meaning of (int) after the variable name

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_type_casting.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's a cast operator - `Math.random()` returns a `double` - you can't convert those to an `int` without potentially losing data (e.g. 4.5 - that would have to become 4). `(int)` is telling java: "Convert it - I'm aware some data might be lost when you do that".

This is called the cast operator, and it's used for all sorts of stuff. When a primitive type is in the parens, it's "convert one primitive type to another".

If java can do it losslessly you don't need to write it. If, however, data could be lost, you do. For example:

```
int x = 5;
long y = x; // fine
int z = y; // not okay
int a = (int) y; // fine
```